# apache mod_wsgi crashes only in daemon mode

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I was using apache webserver and mod_python as my interface.I am in the process of moving from mod_python to mod_wsgi. I have done all the setup and everything was working fine. Now when i added the following line(to enable daemon mode), the site was not working.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess test.tessite.com processes=5 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
```

I got a 500 error as response from the server. When i looked into Apache's error log, i have the follwoing,

```
[Mon Oct 22 12:31:07 2012] [error] [client 58.68.24.230] Premature end of script headers: ls.wsgi
```

This is my WSGI setup in conf,

```
#Set the number of process and threads for each process. process*thread number of requests can be handled at a time
WSGIDaemonProcess test.testsite.com processes=5 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
#Sets which process group WSGI application is assigned to.
WSGIProcessGroup test.testsite.com
#Maps a URL to a filesystem location and designates the target as a WSGI script.
WSGIScriptAlias / /public/gdp/trunk/src/ukl/lis/process/ls.wsgi
<Directory /public/gdp/trunk/src/ukl/lis/process/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Why does this happen only in Daemon mode? How, to fix this problem? Is it safe to run in a non-daemon mode?

Comment: The first thing you want to do is determine whether it is a clash with mod_python. Comment out and mod_python directives and disable loading of mod_python. Then retest and see if still occurs. That way you narrow down cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions, section "Apache Process Crashes", last question. Is the mod_python apache module still loaded? Are you using any third party libraries that have a C component?

Comment: That's weird indeed. Can you try a "hello world" WSGI app and see if that works? If, so does it still work if you load all libraries you use in your real app? Can you confirm that your WSGI processes are actually crashing (do the process numbers change?)